# Trying to play an mp4 video on a ruby mongrel server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, video-streaming, mongrel, mp4

Hello I am trying to run a ruby mongrel server on windows 7.  I am using some video-js code to display a video.

```
<title>Waza Player</title>
<script src="video.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    VideoJS.setupAllWhenReady();
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="video-js.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="Video JS">
<body>
  <div class="video-js-box">
    <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="720" height="304" controls="controls" preload="auto">
      <source src="converted/randomvideo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    </video>   
  </div>
</body>
```

when i use the same html and javascript in apache it works just fine.

I have setup the mimetype for mp4 video but that didn't seem to solve the issue.

any help would be appreciated

2011-04-09 06:45:55 -0700: Read error: #><Errno::ECONNABORTED: An established con
nection was aborted by the software in your host machine.>

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/h
ttp_response.rb:140:in `write'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel/h
ttp_response.rb:140:in `write'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:81:in
 `block in process'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/file.rb:87:in `block in
each'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/file.rb:85:in `open'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/file.rb:85:in `each'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:80:in
 `process'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.r
b:165:in `block in process_client'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.r
b:164:in `each'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.r
b:164:in `process_client'

d:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.2.0.pre2-x86-mingw32/lib/mongrel.r
b:291:in `block (2 levels) in run'

Comment: your code is very messy. It can't work any way

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="720" height="304" controls="controlspreload="auto">
  <source src="randomvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: yes just don't know how to quickly convert the tags web development is not generally my thing